# How to run parallel test using NUnit in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, nunit

I am trying to get parallel tests going with NUnit and C# in visual studio using the NUnit3Test adapter and .runsettings file. It's basically this sample from Souce Labs I am unable to get to run in parallel with the NUnit3Test adpter, instead of using the console.

According to the NUnit documentation (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks)is should be sufficient to have a .runsettings files in the project and configure number of workers there.

I tried with this, but test are still running sequentially.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RunSettings>
  <NUnit>
    <NumberOfTestWorkers>4</NumberOfTestWorkers>
  </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tips and tricks" entry is info for the user **of the adapter**. It tells you what you might need to do to configure parallelism of your tests under the adapter **in addition to** the general steps that are involved in the nunit framework itself and assumes you have read all the docs regarding parallel execution.

By default, the nunit framework runs nothing in parallel. The `ParallelizableAttribute` is available to tell it to run a particular test method or fixture in parallel. It can even be used at the assembly level if you are quite sure that all your tests are able to run in parallel.

That last point deserves repeating with emphasis! When you apply `[Parallelizable]` to a test, you are telling the framework that this particular test is capable of running in parallel - that it will not interfere with any other tests. NUnit assumes you know what you are talking about. It will run that test on a separate thread along with other parallelizable tests **even if that causes problems** due to the way the tests are written.

For that reason, you should pick a few tests first and mark them as parallelizable. The main thing that makes a test impossible to run in parallel is that it shares non-readonly state with other tests.

The info you provide in the `.runsettings` file is completely optional. NUnit will use a default value for the number of worker threads if you don't specify it. The main thing is the use of the attribute.

Comment: [Parallelizable] has no effect on my tests, they still run sequentially.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you ask a new question, including the details of how and where you are using [Parallelizable] in your tests. :-)

Comment: For posterity, it turns out the problem was my version of NUnit. Evidently [Parallelizable] exists in version 3.6 so my IDE didn't complain about using it, but it doesn't actually do anything. After upgrading to NUnit 3.7 without making any code changes, my tests suddenly ran in parallel.

Comment: As you probably know, both 3.6 and 3.7 are pretty old. :-)